# How to Describe About Exam Performance

Tags: expressions

I want to know how can I describe that my exams are going good :-

I am doing well in exams.
I am doing great in exams.
My exams are going good.

which is the right way to do it?

Comment: There are other, more slangy ways of saying it. If you feel like you are really **nailing** your exams, you can say, "I am [_acing_](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/ace) my exams." (If you click on that link, scroll down to where it says **verb - transitive**.)

Comment: @J.R. I'm grateful to you that you answered my question. Do you teach English apart from this website?

Answer (score 2):

The last one should probably be "My exams are going well", and I would recommend also that you say "my exams" rather than simply "exams". However, all three would be suitable.

There is a very slight possible difference between the first two and the last one, in that the last one could only apply to exams that you are currently in the process of completing, whereas the first two also mean this, but could also be used to refer to your exams *in general* throughout your schooling, for example:

> Person: People who live away from home while they are studying tend not to do as well.
>
> You: I live away from home, but I am doing well in my exams.

Comment: I have no problem with "My exams are going good" – in informal, conversational English.